# How to access external class in my own window class in netbeans platform?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror, netbeans-platform

I am developing an application in which I want to access another package's class method in my own window class using the Netbeans platform.  However, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Specifically, I want to add a `JScrollPane` to my window class' `JPanel`.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Add the jar containing the class to the [run-time class-path](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#deploy-classpath) of the application.